# How to write a header into multiple worksheet using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am breaking down dataframe by column `OfficeLocation`, and putting excel file in defined folder.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PolicyNumber':['Pol1','Pol2','Pol3','Pol4','Pol5'],
    'OfficeLocation':['San Diego', 'San Diego','San Diego','Vista','Vista'],
    'Premium':[800,300,650,200,700]
})


folder_list = ['San Diego', 'Vista']

for location, d in df.groupby('OfficeLocation'):
    for folder in folder_list:
        if folder == location:            
            d.to_excel(f'\\\\server\user\name\{folder}\{location}.xlsx',sheet_name=location, startrow=4, index=False)
```

But how can I also write a header "Location - San Diego", "Location - Vista" in each excel spreadsheet?

[image]

Comment: Is necesary to use pandas? ...I guess you can add a few lines inside the For with xlsxwriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PolicyNumber':['Pol1','Pol2','Pol3','Pol4','Pol5'],
    'OfficeLocation':['San Diego', 'San Diego','San Diego','Vista','Vista'],
    'Premium':[800,300,650,200,700]
})


folder_list = ['San Diego', 'Vista']

for location, d in df.groupby('OfficeLocation'):
    for folder in folder_list:
        if folder == location:            
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'\\\\server\user\name\{folder}\{location}.xlsx', 
                                    engine='xlsxwriter')
            d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=location, startrow=4, index=False)
            writer.sheets[location].write('A1', 'Office - {}'.format(location))
            writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for late respond. It gives me an error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Username\Documents\Test\testFolder\Untitled-1.py", line 18, in <module>
    writer.sheets[location].write('A1', 'Office - {}'.format(location))
KeyError: 'San Diego'`

Comment: @Oleg I hade a typo in the `to_excel` piece.  See above that should work for you.  I should have pointed it to the `writer` object i made right above it.  Sorry coding when I was tired.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!